# Difference between using @OneToMany and @ManyToMany

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am having some trouble understanding the difference between `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToMany`. When I use `@OneToMany` it defaults to create a JoinTable and if you add the mappedBy attribute you will have bidirectional relationship between two entities.

I have a `Question` that may belong to many `Categories`, and one `Category` may belong to many `Questions`. I don't understand if I should use `@ManyToMany` or `@OneToMany` because for me it seems exactly the same thing, but it is probably not.

Could somebody explain it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Well, the difference is in the design you're trying to reflect using objects.

In your case, every `Question` can be assigned to multiple `Categories` - so that's a sign of `@*ToMany` relationship. Now you have to decide if:

- each `Category` can have only one `Question` assigned to it (it will result in a **unique** constraint which means that **no other Category can refer the same Question**) - this will be `@OneToMany` relationship,
- each `Category` can have multiple `Questions` assigned to it (there will be no unique constraint in the `Category` table) - this will be `@ManyToMany` relationship.

**@OneToMany (Question -> Category)**

This relationship can be represented by join table only if you explicitly define so using `@JoinTable` or when it is a **unidirectional** relationship in which the owning side is the 'One' side (it means that in the `Question` entity you have a collection of `Categories`, but in the `Categories` you don't have any reference to the `Question`).

If you think about it, it seems quite reasonable that the join table is used. There is no other way the DBMS could save a connection between one row in `Question` table with multiple rows in `Categories` table.

However, if you would like to model a bidirectional relationship you need to specify that the `Category` ('Many' side) is the owning side of the relationship. In this case the DBMS can create a join column with foreign key in the `Category` table because each `Category` row can be connected with only one `Question`.

In this way you don't have any join table but simple foreign keys (still, as pointed at the beginning, you can force to create the join table using `@JoinTable`).

**@ManyToMany**

This relationship must be represented as a join table. It basically works very similar to the unidirectional `@OneToMany` relationship, but in this case you may have multiple rows from `Question` joined with multiple rows from `Categories`.

Comment: Awesome explanation. Should have a lot more upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

@ManyToMany relationships have mutually referential foreign keys on both sides of the relationship.  Sometimes, this relationship is mediated by an adjoining table.

@OneToMany relationships have a foreign key on the "one" side and not on the "many" side.  In a @OneToMany relationship, one object is the "parent" and one is the "child". The parent controls the existence of the child.

Remember that a @ManyToMany bi-directional relationship need not be symmetric!

Answer (score 1):

In your Questions & Categories case, you should use @ManyToMany relationship. @ManyToMany basically means that "a Question can belong to many Categories at the same time" and "a Category can contain many Questions at the same time". A new table will automatically be created to store the mappings. Your code would look like this:

```
@Entity
public class Question implements Serializable {
    ...
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Category> categories;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Category implements Serializable {
    ...
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Question> questions;
    ...
}
```

If you use @OneToMany relationship for your Questions and Categories (let's say Category on the One side and Questions on the other), this means that "a Question can only belong to one Category" and "a Category can contain many Questions at the same time". No new table is needed to store the mapping. Instead, a new field will automatically be created in the Many side to record the ID of the One side. Your code would look like this:

```
@Entity
public class Question implements Serializable {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private Category theCategory;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Category implements Serializable {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="theCategory")
    private List<Question> questions;
    ...
}
```